# RxJava causing Horizontal RecyclerView Scrolling Misbehavior

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, rx-java, android-adapter

Im trying to use RxJava to **update** locally an object so i can then send it back to the server after some user input. Im trying to use a Horizontal RecyclerView inside a vertical RecyclerView but trying to use the **RxJava** to communicate asynchronously with Room DB is causing a scrolling misbehavior.
If you have any feedback or need any  other code please let me know.

**Without RxJava**

[image: WithoutRxJava]

**ViewHolder**

```
inner class ScoreViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){

    private val mNumberPickerLocal = view.findViewById(R.id.number_picker_local) as ScrollableNumberPicker
    private val mNumberPickerAway = view.findViewById(R.id.number_picker_away) as ScrollableNumberPicker

    fun bind(scoreboard: Scoreboard, position: Int){

        val home = scoreboard.home
        val away = scoreboard.away

        mNumberPickerLocal.value = home.toInt()
        mNumberPickerAway.value = away.toInt()

        mNumberPickerLocal.setListener { value ->
            println(value)
        }

        mNumberPickerAway.setListener { value ->
            println(value)
        }
    }
}
```

**With RxJava**

[image]

**ViewHolder**

```
inner class ScoreViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){

    private val mNumberPickerLocal = view.findViewById(R.id.number_picker_local) as ScrollableNumberPicker
    private val mNumberPickerAway = view.findViewById(R.id.number_picker_away) as ScrollableNumberPicker

    fun bind(scoreboard: Scoreboard, position: Int){

        val home = scoreboard.home
        val away = scoreboard.away

        mNumberPickerLocal.value = home.toInt()
        mNumberPickerAway.value = away.toInt()

        mNumberPickerLocal.setListener { value ->
            mDisposable.add(userMatchesVM.updateHomeScore(value.toLong(), scoreboard.id)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .doOnComplete { println("LOCAL SCORE = $value") }
                    .subscribe())

            // Gettting Flowable<Object> 
            mDisposable.add(userMatchesVM.getUsermatchByID(scoreboard.id)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .doOnNext {
                        FirestoreBackend.updateFirebaseMatch(it, "SCORE VH")
                    }
                    .subscribe())

        }

        mNumberPickerAway.setListener { value ->
            mDisposable.add(userMatchesVM.updateAwayScore(value.toLong(), scoreboard.id)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .doOnComplete { println("AWAY SCORE = $value") }
                    .subscribe())

            // Gettting Flowable<Object> 
            mDisposable.add(userMatchesVM.getUsermatchByID(scoreboard.id)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .doOnNext {
                        FirestoreBackend.updateFirebaseMatch(it, "WINNER VH")
                    }
                    .subscribe())
        }
    }
}
```

**UsermatchesViewModel.kt**

```
fun updateHomeScore(home: Long, id: String): Completable =
        Completable.fromAction { mFantasyDB.usermatchesDAO().updateHomeScore(home, id) }

fun updateAwayScore(away: Long, id: String): Completable =
        Completable.fromAction { mFantasyDB.usermatchesDAO().updateAwayScore(away, id) }

fun getUsermatchByID(id: String): Flowable<Usermatches> =
        mFantasyDB.usermatchesDAO().getUsermatch(id)
```

**UsermatchesDAO**

```
@Query("update usermatches set home_score = :home where usermatches_id = :id")
fun updateHomeScore(home: Long,  id: String)

@Query("update usermatches set away_score = :away where usermatches_id = :id")
fun updateAwayScore(away: Long, id: String)

@Query("select * from usermatches where usermatches_id = :id limit 1")
fun getUsermatch(id: String): Flowable<Usermatches>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this problem resides in how you implement your type of **Observable**, by this I mean: I was using a `Flowable<Object>` to 1 object, which was causing to refresh it every time an user input was being registered. To solve it I change my **ViewModel and DAO's** to **Single**.

**ViewModel**

```
fun getMatchesByID(id: String): Single<Matches> =
        mFantasyDB.matchesDAO().getMatchesByID(id)
```

**DAO**

```
@Query("select * from matches where match_id = :id")
fun getMatchesByID(id: String): Single<Matches>
```